# what is the effect of soda water on digestion?

Tags: digestive-system

what is the effect of soda water on the process of digestion? As it has been seen that after drinking soda the process is increased...I just want to know that what is the chemistry behind this?

Comment: do you have source for this observation?

Comment: What should happen? It can be slightly acidic due to carbon dioxide which reacted that way. But the stomach is orders of magnitudes more acidic, which makes sure, that the CO$_2$ is removed from the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Soda, anything carbonated causes bloating, which stretches the stomach. Mechanoreceptors in stomach detect the stretching resulting in parasympathetic innervation to GI smooth muscle. This causes an increase in GI motility.

Comment: what about chemistry?

Comment: I think unless your talking about caffeinated drinks, or drinks that contain a chemical that affect the nervous system, it's negligible. carbonated liquids are acidic, but like @chris stated above, it's moot compared to the pH of the stomach.

Answer (score -1):

Due to presence of hydrogen ion in soda water ,H+ ion Concentration in stomach is increasing (common ion effect) it helps in digestion.

Comment: Please extend your answer and provide reputable support for your claims. Unfortunately, failure to do so will result in downvotes or deletion. Please see our [help] page about writing good answers. Thanks!